# Linearizing $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to linearize $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{k}$, ie. getting it on the form $y = ax+b$ and identifying $a$ and $b$.

With a straight forward approach, I end up with the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{k} \Rightarrow ky+kx=xy \Rightarrow y(k-x) = -kx \Rightarrow y = -\frac{kx}{k-x}
\end{align}

This unfortunately does not work, as x is both in the numerator and denominator of the fraction. Is there some other approach I am missing in order to get it on the form $y=ax+b$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! You can't, because it isn't a line; your ending form is correct. Why did you think it was a line?

Comment: There are multiple ways to interpret this question.  Do you want a linear approximation to $y(x)$?  That is normally what I think of when I see "linearize".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments! I made a typo in the title, and changed a to k. I am simply trying to solve an exercise I have been given that states it is possible to rewrite $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{k}$ to the form $y = ax+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. The exercise describes this as linearization, hence why I used that in the title. There is no indication in the exercise that should be done using approximation, hence why I am at a loss on how to solve the problem

Comment: For simplicity let $k=1$. Then you have $xy=x+y$. It should be obvious now, that you can't rewrite this as $y=ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Consequently you have misunderstood something, or there is a typo. Can you show the original exercise here, by a picture?

Comment: One equivalent form which can be useful if you are working with integers is $(x-k)(y-k)=k^2$